# Jettison / String returned as integer when marshalling

Tags: java, json, jettison

There's a 'feature' of Jettison, outlined in a [JIRA entry](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTISON-36) way back in 2008, which refers to the following problem:

Let's say I ask the value of "element" to be "00102"; the output may look like follows:

```
{ "Response": 
    { "element": "00102" }
}
```

but now I set "element" to be "102":

```
{ "Response":
    { "element": 102 }
}
```

I understand Jettison is trying to be helpful... but seriously, I don't need it to decide this sort of thing on my behalf. No-thank-you.

*Current work-around*

For the moment, I've used a solution outlined by the user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14277329/2979421), who adds the following to the bean config:

```
<bean id="simpleConverter" class="org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.SimpleConverter"/>

<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider">
    <property name="typeConverter" ref="simpleConverter"/>
</bean>
```

This partly solves the issue, in so much as to say that all elements are forced to be strings even if they're clearly integers. Now, at least, I know exactly what structure my data is going to hold, and the element type is not going to change from a string to an integer and back again without my knowledge.

*Problem*

However, I'm unable to output another element now as an integer, even if I'd now wish to do so. It seems as if I can only force the output of elements to string across the entire service, rather than on a per-element basis.

Aside from the 'using Jackson' suggestions (which I can't follow, as the framework explicitly uses Jettison) are there any other ways I could specify which elements I'd like to force as a string in my JSON output?

Comment: "the framework explicitly uses Jettison" <-- which framework?

Comment: Internal company framework

Answer (score 1):

The `SimpleConverter` also convert double and booleans to string, and that is a problem.

You can override the default converter only for your 'special' numbers. Unfortunately there is no way to see the context of original field to convert

```
public class MyConverter extends org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.DefaultConverter {

    public Object convertToJSONPrimitive(String text) {
        Object primitive = super.convertToJSONPrimitive(text);

        //Apply your conversion rule;
        if (primitive != null 
                && primitive instanceof Long 
                && text.startsWith("0"))
            return text;
        else 
            return primitive;
    }
}
```

You can see the full code of DefaultConverter [here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jettison/jettison/1.3.5/org/codehaus/jettison/mapped/DefaultConverter.java)

And the CXF configuration

```
<bean id="myConverter" class="MyConverter"/>

<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider">
    <property name="typeConverter" ref="myConverter"/>
</bean>
```